# Laravel and PSR 4 Autoloading not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I've just set up a new Laravel 5 project. I included a `Helpers.php` in the `/app` directory. Here it is:

```
<?php namespace EP\Helpers;

class Helpers {


    public static function sayHi()
    {
        return 'Hi';
    }
}
```

And in the route I am doing:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return EP\Helpers\Helpers::sayHi();
});
```

But when I hit that route I am getting the error:

```
Class 'EP\Helpers\Helpers' not found
```

The funny thing is, PHPStorm is able to auto detect the namespace. Anyone know why this would be happening?

Comment: I believe in your case the namespace would be `Ep`.

Comment: I renamed the project name using artisan to 'EP'. Instead of using 'App' as the root, I use 'EP'.

Comment: But when you use `EP\Helpers\Helpers`, there is no `Helpers` directory.

Comment: ooooooh I got you. Put that as an answer because it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe in your case the namespace would be:

```
<?php namespace EP;
```